# SWIG generated names too long

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm wrapping some C++ code with SWIG to generate java code. I have this typedef

```
typedef void (*create_cb_t)(const rib_handle_t rib,
            const cdap_rib::con_handle_t &con,
            const std::string& fqn,
            const std::string& class_,
            const cdap_rib::filt_info_t &filt,
            const int invoke_id,
            const ser_obj_t &obj_req,
            ser_obj_t &obj_reply,
            cdap_rib::res_info_t& res);
```

Which is later used in a member function

```
        void addCreateCallbackSchema(const cdap_rib::vers_info_t& version,
                                 const std::string& class_,
                                 const std::string& fqn_,
                                 create_cb_t cb);
```

When SWIG generates the type the file name is too long and it gives an error when using it

```
Unable to open file ../../../java/eu/irati/librina/SWIGTYPE_p_f_q_const__long_long_r_q_const__rina__cdap_rib__connection_handler_r_q_const__std__string_r_q_const__std__string_r_q_const__rina__cdap_rib__filtering_info_q_const__int_r_q_const__rina__ser_obj_r_rina__ser_obj_r_rina__cdap_rib__result_info__void.java: File name too long
```

How can I replace (I suppose rename) the typedef with a name that avoids this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to create an specific typedef in the interface file (respect the namespace):

```
namespace rina {
namespace rib{
    typedef void (*create_cb_t)(const rib_handle_t rib,
    const cdap_rib::con_handle_t &con, 
    const std::string& fqn,
    const std::string& class_,
    const cdap_rib::filt_info_t &filt,
    const int invoke_id,
    const ser_obj_t &obj_req,
    ser_obj_t &obj_reply,
    cdap_rib::res_info_t& res);
}}
```

and then ignore the typedef in .h

```
#ifndef SWIG
typedef void (*create_cb_t)(const rib_handle_t rib,
            const cdap_rib::con_handle_t &con,
            const std::string& fqn,
            const std::string& class_,
            const cdap_rib::filt_info_t &filt,
            const int invoke_id,
            const ser_obj_t &obj_req,
            ser_obj_t &obj_reply,
            cdap_rib::res_info_t& res);
#endif
```